# phpactiverecord retrieve records

Tags: arrays, object, phpactiverecord

Let's make it short, I pass an user id into a function and try to get all attributes for this user:

`$user = \Sitename\UsrManager::getUserById($user_id);`

I then `print_r($user)` and get a bunch of data:

```
Sitename\User Object ( [model:protected] => User Object ( [errors] => [attributes:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array ( [user_id] => 18 [company_name] => ABC Ltd [company_logo] => logo.png [brief] => Sample text [profile] => Some Profile ) [__dirty:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array ( ) [__readonly:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => [__relationships:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array ( ) [__new_record:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => ) [_password_updated:Sitename\User:private] => [template:protected] =>
```

If I want to get specific attribute such as **Company Name**, I try echo the company name as `$user->company_name`, but there is nothing to show, what is the proper way to call data(object?) in my example? it's like similar to the old way to call the necessary data like `$row['company_name']`.

Comment: You should be able to do just that (`$user->company_name`). Are you sure you've run a good test? Could you show an output where you first do `$print_r($user)`, and then `$print_r($user->company_name)` ?

Comment: @Nanne, I had checked whether `$user` is an array, it returned as not an array, thought its causes `$user->company_name` never return a value.

Comment: `$user` is not an array as you can see, it is an object. Even better, it is an phpactiverecord object (I presume). That's why you should be able to do `$user->company_name`. You don't need to do thinks like getting to the `attributes` variable, because phpAR does that for you. But can you do what I asked?

Comment: Also make sure you don't have e function inside of Sitename\User called `get_company_name()`, as that will override what happens when you do `$user->company_name`.